# objective c arrays linked somehow

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Hi i have an  array which i am trying to copy then remove an element from.  The issue is i think i am removing the element from the copy but it also removes the element from the original array.  I have no idea what is going on.  Im new to objective c so any help would be much appreciated.

```
NSArray *newarray = appDelegate.orginalArray;

[newarray removeObjectAtIndex: 2];
```

When i look at the arrays after removing the object it had removed it from both newarray and orginalArray why would this be?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't making a copy. Both `newArray` and `appDelegate.originalArray` refer to the same object. You would need to do this:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [appDelegate.originalArray mutableCopy];
```

Also note that I'm using `NSMutableArray` and `mutableCopy` to ensure the copy is mutable (i.e. supports adding and removing items)

Answer (score 0):

Pointers, buddy, and mutable/immutable abstractions. `newarray` and `appDelegate.originalArray` are both pointers (references) to the same immutable (unchangeable) array. You want:

```
NSArray *newarray = [appDelegate.orginalArray mutableCopy];
```